# Set experimental flags chrome via command line

Tags: google-chrome

I want to be able to set the following experimental flag in a cronjob.
[image]

However, I can't get it to work without using the GUI.
There are a couple of answers here but nothing seems to work for me.

This does not work`google-chrome --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode`

I tried `google-chrome --enable-features=enableforcedark` according to [this](https://www.itechtics.com/add-experimental-features-chrome-command-line/), does not work.

So, how can I set this flag?

Comment: why are you starting chrome in a cronjob?

Comment: I only start chrome via keyboard shortcuts. So I want to change the shortcut command in a cronjob to start chrome with or without this flag.